# Delphi iOS ListBox force selection update

Tags: ios, delphi, listbox, firemonkey

The way Delphi by default updates the selection with a timer can sometimes look funny if people scroll very fast (losing track), so I would like to disable that.

However, what I would like instead is that it would update selection immediately on the **OnItemClick** event. (i.e. I would like to force update the selection immediately before hen doing the rest of processing in the click event - that would be quite excellent.) However, after having tried quite a few things, this appears quite a bit more cumbersome to achieve than first expected.

I have tried force update selection, force animations, force updateselection etc. but none update the selection because of internal properties. Has anyone sucessfully done with without making changes to the listbox code directly?